# Splitting JSON string into multiple JSON strings in Java

Tags: java, json

I have got a JSON structure similar to below:

```json
{
  "MyApp": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "MyPath1": {
      "Key": "Value"
    },
    "MyPath2": {
      "Key": "Value"
    }
  }
}
```

Within `paths` there could be a variable number of `MyPath` keys. I want to break this structure into something like below:

- JSON 1:

```json
{
  "MyApp": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "MyPath1": {
      "Key": "Value"
    }
  }
}
```

- JSON 2:

```json
{
  "MyApp": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "MyPath2": {
      "Key": "Value"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any simple approach I can opt for this in Java?

Comment: You can delete part of json object like this

delete arr.paths.MyPath2;

So add your json to two var's, and from 1st remove 1st mypath, from 2nd  remove 2nd my path.

https://jsfiddle.net/h20voga5/

That is what you need if i am not mistaken

Comment: Thanks for the response.. Good thought but the problem is i don't know how many `Mypath` will be there inside my `paths` .What i am thinking is Keep the JSON in one `JSONObject` and remove the `paths` key from the JSON and store it in a separate  `JSONObject` and iterate over this 2nd object and add `Mypath`  to 1st json. But problem with this is my `JSONObject` is not recognize `MyPath1` and `2` and the Keyset values in my 2nd json.. Hope i didn't confuse you ;)

Comment: Oh i see, i have worked a lot with json where i dont know what is in and how many of objects are coming , you can check this question i answered where it automaticly generates html from json (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528886/dynamic-ui-from-json-object/38530570#38530570),  you should just check for length of paths , and do while loop for it , and generate new JSON object where it does delete for each myPath (check for indexing and take objName with object.keys) that will have split paths.  If you dont manage to do it , ill try to make JSfiddle after work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Jackson, a popular JSON parser for Java, you can have the following:

```java
String json = "{\"MyApp\":\"2.0\",\"info\":{\"version\":\"1.0.0\"},\"paths\":"
            + "{\"MyPath1\":{\"Key\":\"Value\"},\"MyPath2\":{\"Key\":\"Value\"}}}";

// Create an ObjectMapper instance the manipulate the JSON
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

// Create a list to store the result (the list will store Jackson tree model objects)
List<JsonNode> result = new ArrayList<>();

// Read the JSON into the Jackson tree model and get the "paths" node
JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(json);
JsonNode paths = tree.get("paths");

// Iterate over the field names under the "paths" node
Iterator<String> fieldNames = paths.fieldNames();
while (fieldNames.hasNext()) {

    // Get a child of the "paths" node
    String fieldName = fieldNames.next();
    JsonNode path = paths.get(fieldName);

    // Create a copy of the tree
    JsonNode copyOfTree = mapper.valueToTree(tree);

    // Remove all the children from the "paths" node; add a single child to "paths"
    ((ObjectNode) copyOfTree.get("paths")).removeAll().set(fieldName, path);

    // Add the modified tree to the result list
    result.add(copyOfTree);
}

// Print the result
for (JsonNode node : result) {
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(node));
    System.out.println();
}
```

The output is:

```json
{
  "MyApp" : "2.0",
  "info" : {
    "version" : "1.0.0"
  },
  "paths" : {
    "MyPath1" : {
      "Key" : "Value"
    }
  }
}

{
  "MyApp" : "2.0",
  "info" : {
    "version" : "1.0.0"
  },
  "paths" : {
    "MyPath2" : {
      "Key" : "Value"
    }
  }
}
```

A new JSON will be created for each child of the `paths` node.

Comment: Thank you. If i want to explore more features of this jackson is there any good way to tht?

Answer (score 0):

Try something on following lines..not perfect but a start..

1. Convert the Json to Java object. You may need a java class or Pojo to map to it ( Unless you already have one).
   Var MyApp;
   var List  list;
2. Convert the Java object back to Json object in required format. Read each item

   - Always add the MyApp
     Iterate over the List list
     add to JsonObjectCollection
3. Return all object and use them as needed

Answer (score 0):

EDIT (Just noticed that its needed in Java , my bad ) 
--There might be easier way to do it but here is the solution i got.
When you import your JSON save it to 2 vars , one will be used for creating new object.
Create newArr for all new objects.
I am looping through all paths and create newPath which is saved in newObjectsArray and then pushed to newArr.
Then you can access all your objects through that array.
If you have multiple myApps , you can make $each which will take upper data and create new json, and just move while loop inside it

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/h20voga5/2/

```
      var arr = {
 "MyApp":"2.0",
   "info":{  
      "version":"1.0.0"
   },
   "paths":{  
      "MyPath1":{
      "Key":"Value1"
      },
      "MyPath2":{
      "Key":"Value2"
      }
}
}

var newObjectArray = {
 "MyApp":"2.0",
   "info":{  
      "version":"1.0.0"
   },
   "paths":{  
      "MyPath1":{
      "Key":"Value1"
      },
      "MyPath2":{
      "Key":"Value2"
      }
}
}

var newArr = {'Data':[]}  
var length = Object.keys(arr.paths).length; 
var i = 0


while(i < length){
 newObjectArray.paths = {} 
  var objectKey = Object.keys(arr.paths)[i] // MyPath1, MyPath2...
  var objectValues = JSON.stringify(arr.paths[objectKey]) // {"Key":"Value1"} 
  var newPath = '{'+ objectKey + ':' +  objectValues+'}'

  newObjectArray.paths = newPath 
  newArr.Data.push(newObjectArray)


  i++
}


var countObjects = newArr.Data.length
alert(countObjects)
alert(JSON.stringify(newArr.Data[0])) // access your objects like this
```

Comment: I understand the OP wants to do it in Java.

Comment: I just noticed it , well i gave him some logic to work on :) my bad