# How to load huge amount of data from spring boot to reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, rest, spring-websocket, data-stream

I have two applications, spring boot backend and react frontend. I need to load a lot of data (lets say 100 000 objects, each 3 Integer fields), and present it on a leaflet map. However i don't know which protocol should I use. I thought about two approaches:

1. Do it with REST, 1 000 (or more/less) objects each request, create some progress bar on front end so user does not refresh the page all the time because he thinks something is wrong.
2. Do it with websocket, so it is faster? Same idea with progress bar, however I am worried that if user starts to refresh the page, backend will stream the data even though connection from frontend is crashed and new one is established, for the new one the process will begin too, and so on.

If it is worth mentioning, I am using spring-boot 2.3.1, together with spring cloud (eureka, spring-cloud-gateway). Websocket i chose is SockJS, data is being streamed by SimpMessagingTemplate from org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate.

Comment: When talking about REST, I use project reactor in my application, so all responses are FLUX.

Answer (score 0):

If you have that amount of data and alot of read write operations, I would recommend not returning it in either websocket or rest call(reactor or MVC) sending big amount of data over tcp has it issues, what I would recommend is quite simple, save the data to Storage(AWS S3 for example), return the S3 bucket url, and from the client side read the data from the S3 directly,

alternatively you can have a message queue that the client is subscribe on(pub/sub), publish the data in the server side, and subscribe to it on the client side, but this may be an overkill.

If you are set on rest you can use multipart data see the stack overflow question here:

[Multipart example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822468/send-a-large-response-json-as-multipart-data-or-in-multiple-parts)